# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException' in xcode 13.2.1

Tags: swift, facebook

**Here is my error message**

> Thread 1: "Starting with v13 of the SDK, a client token must be
> embedded in your client code before making Graph API calls.\nVisit
> https://developers.facebook.com/apps//settings/advanced/
> to find your client token for this app.\nAdd a key named
> FacebookClientToken to your Info.plist, and add your client token as
> its value.\nVisit
> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started#configure-your-project
> for more information."

500 errors are given to perform the action.